# Recommended way to start supervisord from non-root bash script?

Tags: root, supervisord

I have set up supervisor to monitor some processes. Because I deploy via remote script, I need a way to send supervisor start/stop commands without sudo. I'm not sure how to do this though.

Is there a way in supervisor to run specified commands as a non root user?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `supervisorctl` command can be run as a non-root user. All you need to do is give it permission to connect to the `supervisord` process.

You'll need to configure access in the appropriate server section, so in the [`[unix_http_server]` section](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#unix-http-server-section-values), or in the [`[inet_http_server]` section](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#inet-http-server-section-settings), whichever you are using for your `supervisord` setup.

If you use the `[unix_http_server]` setup, you'd add `chmod` and/or `chown` directives to control who can access the UNIX domain socket, for example:

```
[unix_http_server]
chown = youruser
```

so that `youruser` can write to that socket, which means `supervisorctl` can send `supervisord` commands. You can also add a group:

```
[unix_http_server]
chown = youruser:yourgroup
```

Finally, you'll have to restart `supervisord` itself with `service supervisor restart`

Comment: Thanks, also I tried to define a process group but supervisor isn't seeing it, even after a restart of supervisord itself. Is there some config I'm missing other than a [group:x] with programs & priority defined?

Comment: @user1561108: You mean you added a `[group:groupname]` section and after a restart you don't see that added? `[group:]` sections don't specify permissions to access it, only an easy way to address a whole group of programs (to restart them together, for example), so I am a little confused if this still applies to your original question.